Is this a Bank security device?
I just found it at the back of my drawers.  We started using the online banking before internet and had similar devices for security.  They were replaced, possibly with these.
I just want to decide if I should throw it away, keep it or return to the bank.


This is a Vasco DIGIPASS 260 series code generator.
It can be used by banks and any other online or offline service as an authentication device.
Since it is a generic device, it may be possible to customize it, maybe make it use your own keys and then have a physical authenticator.
